# Save updated image from recyclerview and show when offline Android

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-glide

I am very new in Android. In my app I have a rest api that contains information of users of a company. for exmaple name, email, phone etc. I also implement image with this information. The image list are coming from a url. I uses Glide image library to show that images. Now the problem is before I used .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) this line to cache the image into device. It always show the previous stored image. I have tried also with picasso. But when user take a new photo the image is not updated. So I write the follwing.

```
 .skipMemoryCache( true )
 .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
```

Now a new problem, when user gets offline no image on the imageview. I would like to save the updated image and show into recyclerview even when the user is offline. I am reding so many articles on stack overflow from yester. But did not find any suitable answer for this.

I have imaplement Glide in adapter in the follwing way

```
Glide.with( holder.itemView.getContext() )
                    .load( Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail() )
                    .skipMemoryCache( true )
                    .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
                    .signature( new StringSignature( String.valueOf(Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail() ) ) )
                    .into( holder.colleaguePicture );
```

Is there any way to save image from url and show into reyclerview.

May be this is not related but I gave for understaning the activity class

```
    public class MyColleaguesPage extends AppCompatActivity implements MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueListListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);


        if (getNetworkAvailability()) {
            rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            recyclerView = this.findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyColleaguesPage.this));
            recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());

            myColleagueList = new ArrayList<>();

            sendRequest();

        } else {

            colleagueConfigViews();
        }


    public boolean getNetworkAvailability() {
        return Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void sendRequest() {

        trustAllCertificates();

        CookieHandler.setDefault( cookieManager );

        if (cookieManager==null) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( Request.Method.GET, UPLOAD_URL + "/api/users", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        MyColleagueModel mycolleague = new MyColleagueModel();

                        try {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject( i );

                            mycolleague.setName( object.optString( "name" ) );
                            mycolleague.setGivenName( object.optString( "givenName" ) );
                            mycolleague.setCompany( object.optString( "company" ) );
                            mycolleague.setTitle( object.optString( "title" ) );
                            mycolleague.setMail( object.optString( "mail" ) );
                            mycolleague.setMobile( object.optString( "mobile" ) );
                            mycolleague.setDepartment( object.optString( "department" ) );

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        myColleagueList.add( mycolleague );

                    }

                    adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter( myColleagueList, MyColleaguesPage.this );

                    recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i( "Volley Error: ", error.toString() );
                }
            } );

            rq.add( jsonArrayRequest );
        }
    }

}
```

**Updated Answer**

```
 Glide.with( holder.itemView.getContext() )
                .load( Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail() )
                .skipMemoryCache(getNetworkAvailability())

                .signature( new StringSignature( String.valueOf(Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail() ) ) )
                .into( holder.colleaguePicture );



 public boolean getNetworkAvailability() {
    return Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context);
}
```

Comment: Glide automatically stores images in cache, no need to think about it.

Comment: @RavindraPawar yes I know. But my question was not that. I would like to save image in backend. But if online I would like to show the upsdated image. That is why I   use .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE ). But now no image in offline

Comment: Is there any way when new image come,, the previous loading image would be override

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the problem: your recycler view show the previous image for a while and then this image is updated with the new one when downloaded, right?

If this is the error then u can easily fix it by telling to glide to put a placeholder in your image view in the onBindViewHolder method.

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) // <-- this should fix
  .into(view);
```

If you do not have a placeholder then you can set a null image to the imageView:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(null); //empty imageView
```

This allows you to **restore the glide's cache behaviour**.

**Why it happen?**
The recycler view will reuse rows that have been show previously creating the strange effect you notice. The image view of a reused row will show the previous image if you don't tell glide to immediatly show something else as a placeholder.

### Edit

The only way to tell glide to invalidate a cached resource is using:

```
.signature()
```

providing your own way to determine if an image has been updated by the user. The server should provide this type of information. Maybe in a user detail response the server could add the lastModifiedPicture timestamp. Given that you could instrument your signature function and tell glide to download the new image.

#### Example (from glide github):

```
Glide.with(yourFragment)
    .load(yourFileDataModel)
    .signature(new StringSignature("your signature string derived from the lastModifiedPicture timestamp"))
    .into(yourImageView);
```

Is the only way.

Comment: If I write .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)  this line, it takes too much time for loading the pic. My problem is in online can see the images. But when i used  .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL). it saves the images and also I can see offile. But I have a photo uploading funtionality. With this line i could not updated the picture.

Comment: Ho w can I update the new image and at the same time store that updated image to override the previous image

Comment: I have edited the question.  the behavios is same. at fist i start the app. And reyclerview is showing all the images from urls. I can store image same as before changing the code. Now I upload a new image. and i go the recyclerview. I see the old image. not the image. But if i wrire .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE ) I can see the latest image. But in offline the iage is empty. no image there

Comment: do you have any update for my question. I am really suffering fpr this issue from 2 days

Comment: have u tried the solution i wrote in the second part of my reply?

Comment: I have used .signature( new StringSignature( Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail() ) ), but that is not working. could you please tell me how can i define my own StringSignature

Comment: i told you... you should use an information that come from the server. You have to implement it. Actually you're using a string that does not help you at all. The signature string that you create will not change if the image change on the server. Tell to the guy that implemented your backend code to add a timestamp field to your "user detail json response" that indicate when the user has updated his profile picture and use this field to generate the signature